# How do you pass a mediaStream to Angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, media, angular-directive, getusermedia

I have an application that takes pictures on several pages.  I have a camera service that configures the camera and captures the images.  Naturally the user would like to preview the picture before capturing.  So I would like to preview the camera stream in an angular-ui $modal.

This [Camera Test Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pthalacker/b1cs14uo/10/) is doing what I want, but when I try to assign the camera service stream to the src attribute of the target video element in the directive

```
   function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
     cameraService.getCamera()
    .then(function(stream){
       element.find('video').attr("src", stream);
    });
```

I get the following error

[image]

It has something to do with how angular builds the html. I am a getUserMedia novice, so any suggestions for a work-around?

Comment: I don't know if you updated it but this code is working fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/pthalacker/b1cs14uo/10/ or I misunderstand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me

```
  function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
     cameraService.getCamera()
    .then(function(stream){
       var blob = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
       element.attr("src", blob);
       element[0].play();
    });
  }
```